# What is wrong with my concatenate formula for date in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-format

I've been in this trouble for some times.
I have "Oxford" in cell A1 and "02 January 2019" in cell B1 and I want to merge these two cells separated with a comma and single space.

I've tried

```
=A1&", "&text(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy;@")
```

and

```
=concatenate(A1,", ",text(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy;@"))
```

but none of them worked.

Do you have any idea what was wrong with my formula?

Comment: Your formulas both seem to work for me for the expected result you say you cannot get. What result are you getting and show what you'd like to get instead. Simply [edit] and add that detail as it might be helpful.

Comment: Is the date in B1 possibly text?

Comment: It appears to work properly whether B1 contains a date or text.  If text, it displays the text as entered.  If a date, it uses the month name in Indonesian (code [$-421]), which appears as "Januari".

Comment: The formulas work in my environment. What the wrong result did you get? Please provide the wrong result.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I've never seen the `[$-421]` stuff used before.  What is that? Is there a list of countries that applies to? It seems to translate the `dd` in to whatever language the `$-###` numbers are?

Comment: @BruceWayne, yeah, that was a new one for me, too.  Had to research it, and it's a bit obscure.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409.  Here's a sortable list of locale codes: https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it and its not possible to answer without further information

Answer (score -1):

**To get the correct result, your Formula should be written like this:**

`=A1&", "&TEXT(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy")`

`=CONCATENATE(A1,", ",TEXT(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy"))`

Both will return,,

[image]

**N.B.** *Above shown Formulas are working properly even when in Cell `B1` the **DATE has entered as TEXT.***

**Note,** Sometimes this Formula returns ZERO.

`=A1&", "&text(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy;@")`

Somewhere, I found **Date Format** like this

`MM/DD/YYYY;@`

and **Number Format** like

`_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)`

**Edited:**

But **;@** with **Date** and **_(@)** with **Number** doesn't makes any difference or scene **unless is not been used properly**.

- Basically **@** is a **Text placeholder**, which can be used to apply the **Font Color** to *Text values.*
- Suppose this Formula is written in Cell `C1`,

`=A1&", "&TEXT(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy")`

and then after if you apply this Format to Cell `C1`,

`General; General; General;[Red] "Date is, "@`

**Or** `[Red] "Date is, "@`

you get,

[image]

Comment: Your formula is the same as the OP's except it leaves out the ampersand, which serves a purpose (then you talk about that and say that it also works).  A number of people commented that the OP's formula works.  So almost all of the answer is saying that it ought to work (but the OP reports that it doesn't).  You report sometimes getting a zero, which might be replicating the OP's problem, but then the answer doesn't explain why or how to fix it, which was the question.

Comment: @fixer1234,, when I tried his Formula `=A1&", "&text(B1,"[$-421]dd mmmm yyyy;@")` given ZERO many times but when i removed the `;@` sign it works and what I've mentioned also. Somewhere I've found that the `;;;@' replaces ZERO with Blanks and since the Formula doesn't have any special feature to explain so I decided to concise my answer. Thanks for observation,, soon I'll edit the post☺

Comment: @fixer1234,, check the edited part show how to use `@` with Formula.

Comment: Most of the answer isn't responsive to the question, it's a lot of distracting stuff to read through. The @ in the question is a placeholder for text in the cell content, it has nothing to do with color. There's nothing obvious wrong with the OP's formula, it works for other readers. The OP didn't describe how it doesn't work.  Your earlier observation that you sometimes got a zero was the only evidence that someone besides the OP got it to do anything unexpected.  So if you can explain how you got a zero, that could possibly explain the OP's problem.  But nothing in the answer does that.